# how I process NullPointerException on android?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

[image]I want 
when I click the button.
showing Connectingreceiver.class

but NullpointerException.
I think I not well use context.
advice for me 
thanks android senior developer.

```
private OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    Context context= ConfiguredNetworkContent.this;

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


       Intent intent = new Intent(context,Connectingreceiver.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent);





 public class Connectingreceiver extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.connecting_dialog);


}
}
```

Comment: call `this.context = context;`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya   in constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

```
private View.OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Connectingreceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Update :**

Straight forward explanation is you need a `Context` to start a `Activity`. And in `Onclick()` there is a passing View in which `Context` already existed. So, I only used it to start activity.

Comment: I try this but   `context.startActivity(intent)`    , `startActivity(v.getContext());`   NPE ;)

Comment: thanks I try this :)

Comment: I try  `public static void customstartActivity (Context context){`   and `    customstartActivity(v.getContext());`       Likewise
 NPE

Comment: remove your static word

Comment: `   context.startActivity(intent);`     ` customstartActivity(v.getContext());`   NPE

Comment: thanks but change my post  check please

Comment: oh perfect  thanks sayem

Comment: can I one more question?

Comment: yes .. you can....

Comment: recently when I click wifi connect button.
showing Connectreceiver.class (activity)  

I want when finish wifi connect (=connected state)

finish app (=kill app)

How can I do?

Comment: Sorry you need to explain more.You need to add a new question about it & need to give the steps & proper code about it. In this way many people can help u with that.

Comment: ok thanks,   why your answer is correct ? explain please

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: thanks.. perhap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258588/how-can-when-i-wi-fi-change-and-connected-wifi-finish-app-on-android     if you possible please help me

Answer (score 1):

where this context?  `Context context;`

fix `Context context = getApplicationContext;`

Comment: 2 line Context context;

Comment: oh ..add command this.    onClick  extends BaseContent.  BaseContent is abstract class. not extends

Comment: @조현욱 Context context; the same as Context context = null;

Comment: @조현욱 startActivity(getApplicationContext);

Comment: I try Context context;  -> change (Context context = null;) and customstartActivity(getApplicationContext)      customstartActivity is I post it method

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Add this line after Main class
Button yourButton;
```

In below code don't forget to edit "yourButtonIDfromXML"

```
// Add below code in OnCreate method after setContentView
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonIDfromXML);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ConfiguredNetworkContent.this, Connectingreceiver.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: it cannot resolve constructor message  (this,Connectingreceiver.class) this part

Comment: Can you post the logcat

Comment: Update post. code change and logcat

Comment: try the edited code.

Comment: thanks but already  correct answer

Comment: ah.. ?  upvote is what mean?

Comment: just click the up arrow to the left side of my answer

Answer (score 0):

> I think I not well use context.

You have to use it if needed, But as per your codes there is no initialization of `context`.

First initialize your `context` either with `ApplicationContext` or `ActivityContext` like here

```
Context context = YourActivity.this;
```

then you can use `startActivity(intent);`. You don't need to write `context.startActivity(intent);`. only `startActivity` will be enough at all.

**UPDATE :**

Do not pass any context their just simply do

```
customstartActivity();
```

And inside `customstartActivity()` method

```
public static void customstartActivity (){
 //  Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, Connectingreceiver.class);
 //  Intent intent = new Intent(ContextWrapper.getBaseContext(), Connectingreceiver.class);
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Connectingreceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I try `private OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new OnClickListener(){ Context context = myclass.this;`

Comment: and `@Override public void onClick(View v){ Intent intent = new Intent(context, ,Connectingreceiver.class); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent) ;'   but 'Intent intent = new Intent(context,Connectingreceiver.class);'  this part NPE

Comment: And will this work if you put `getApplicationContext()` in the place of `context`.

Comment: I try  in onClick   `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Connectingreceiver.class);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(intent);`    but NPE error.. sorry @Shree Krishna

Comment: Is `Connectingreceiver` a seperate Activity (class) or same as you've shown their ?

Comment: `Connectingreceiver` only `public class Connectingreceiver extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.connecting_dialog);


}
}`

Comment: my class is extends BaseContent.   BaseContent is abstract class extends Activity

Comment: See my update. And see the commented intent too.. Use whichever you prefer. Don't be so complex.

Answer (score 0):

The "context" - is null. You need to do null check s to avoid Null Pointer Crash. It is the easiest exception to resolve.

If your are doing OnClick event in

1. Activity:- Use these lines.

   public static void startReceiver() {

   ```
       Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Connectingreceiver.class);
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```
2. Fragment :-
   Use these lines

   private OnClickListener mConnectOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

   ```
   Context context;
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if(getActivity() != null) {
           startActivity(getActivity());
       }
   }
   ```

   And use same the startActivity() method

Also, rename your startActivity method. It is an inbuilt android method. 
Prefer using camel cases for your class name.  Connectingreceiver --> ConnectingReceiver.

Comment: I try  1. Activity : use these lines .    error message `cannot resolve constructor this class, Connectingreceiver.class

Comment: and 2 fragment try  `cannot resolve symbol`    my class is extends basecontent   . basecontent is I create abstract class

Comment: try this - Intent intent = new Intent(this,Connectingreceiver.class); - for activity

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: basecontent is activity