# How can close app when WIFI is connected?

Tags: android

recently when I click wifi connect button.
showing Connectreceiver.class (activity)

I want when finish wifi connect (=connected state)

finish app (=kill app)

How can I do?

```
public class Connectingreceiver extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.connecting_dialog);

  registerReceiver(progressFinish, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
    }
private BroadcastReceiver progressFinish = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();


        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if(action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)){
            if(networkInfo.getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                finish();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        }

    }





};
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    try{
        unregisterReceiver(progressFinish);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does your code have errors? Using `finish();` is actually correct

Comment: Check out [finishAffinity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/437146) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/how-to-exit-from-the-application-and-show-the-home-screen). Please google properly before posting query on SO.

Comment: do a broadcastreciver for wifi and finish your app accordingly.